# 3D model over iPhone camera images. Transparent background?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to make an augmented reallity app for iPhone where you can see, over the camera images, 3D models built using OpenGL ES. I've already made the part where I get the images from the camera and a GLView that inherits from UIView where I draw the model. My problem is that when I put the GLView over the camera images, you don't see only the model but a black rect covering all the view. I've tried to colour the background so it becomes transparent but I haven't got it. Do you know which one could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself. Appart from using `glClearColor` when you draw the `OpenGl` View, you need to have in mind to things:

- When you create your `CAEAGLayer` object, you have to assign its opaque property the value    `NO`.
- When you assign the `drawableProperties`, you have to choose a color format that admits transparency, for example `kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8`.

Hope this will be useful to someone else! Thanks Benjamin Andris for your answer anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the 'opaque' property of your GLView to NO?